# dataclasses use InitVar default to set instance attribute

Tags: python, default-value, python-dataclasses

When you provide a default for an `InitVar` typed variable in a dataclass, the attribute
for that variable is set (actually, for variables that lack a default the attribute seems to be
actively deleted in `dataclasses:_process_class()`).

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, InitVar, fields

@dataclass
class HasDefault:
    abc: int = 18
    xyz: InitVar[str] = 'oops'

    def __post_init__(self, xyz):
        self.abc += len(xyz)

@dataclass
class NoHasDefault:
    abc: int
    xyz: InitVar[str]

    def __post_init__(self, xyz):
        self.abc += len(xyz)


hd = HasDefault(abc=42, xyz='so long...')
print('field names', [field.name for field in fields(hd)])
print(hd, hd.abc, hd.xyz)
print()
hd2 = HasDefault(abc=42)
print('field names', [field.name for field in fields(hd2)])
print(hd2, hd2.abc, hd2.xyz)
print()
hd3 = HasDefault()
print('field names', [field.name for field in fields(hd3)])
print(hd3, hd3.abc, hd3.xyz)
print()
nhd = NoHasDefault(abc=42, xyz='so long...')
print('field names', [field.name for field in fields(nhd)])
print(nhd, getattr(nhd, 'xyz', 'no attribute xyz'))
```

which gives:

```
field names ['abc']
HasDefault(abc=52) 52 oops

field names ['abc']
HasDefault(abc=46) 46 oops

field names ['abc']
HasDefault(abc=22) 22 oops

field names ['abc']
NoHasDefault(abc=52) no attribute xyz
```

Why is the attribute `xyz` set **at all** for `InitVar` typed variables (when there is a default)? I expected this attribute never to be set as it is only for initialisation. Is this a bug?

`mypy` actually complains that those instances have no attribute `xyz`, so it seems to handle `InitVar` differently.

Because of this I needed to add some extra lines to get loading such a `dataclass`
from YAML to work in the same way, as normally the value from the YAML mapping
would be used to set the attribute, instead of the default. So what you can do (in `ruamel.yaml>0.17.34) is:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, InitVar
from typing import ClassVar
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

yaml = YAML()

@yaml.register_class
@dataclass
class HasDefault:
    yaml_tag: ClassVar = '!has_default'  # if not set the class name is taken ('!HasDefault')
    abc: int
    xyz: InitVar[str] = 'oops'

    def __post_init__(self, xyz):
        self.abc += len(xyz)

yaml_str = """\
!has_default
abc: 42
xyz: hello world
"""

data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
print(data, data.xyz == 'oops')
```

giving:

```
HasDefault(abc=53) True
```

otherwise `data.xyz` would equal `hello world`